# Animate svg path fill using css

Tags: css, animation, svg

It is possible to change svg fill using css. But I didn't manage to create an animation.
Here is my svg object:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="tick" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 60 60" enable-background="new 0 0 60 60" xml:space="preserve"> 
<rect id="fill" x="21" y="26" width="60" height="60"/>
</svg>
```

And, using SASS:

```
@include keyframes(loading)
  0%
    fill: black
  50%
    fill: white
  100%
    fill: black
#fill
  fill: white
  @include animation(loading 3s infinite)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**

Okay it looks like something like this should work.

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="tick" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 60 60" enable-background="new 0 0 60 60" xml:space="preserve"> 
  <style type="text/css" >
        <![CDATA[

          @keyframes fill {
              0% {
                  fill: black;
              }
              50% {
                  fill: white;
              }
              100% {
                  fill: black;
              }
          }

          #fill {
              fill: black;
              animation-name: fill;
              animation-duration: 3s;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          }

        ]]>
    </style>
    <rect id="fill" x="21" y="26" width="60" height="60"/>
</svg>
```

Here is the example: http://jsbin.com/ayiheb/2/edit

Comment: Thanks =) But I need to animate a particular shape #fill.

Comment: @evergreenv Ah okay. Is there a reason it needs to be done in CSS instead of the animate tag in SVG?

Comment: @evergreenv By the way, updated the answer with something that should work. Let me know!

Comment: I want to be able to trigger animation using class, and don't want to create additional svg with animation. Or it is possible to turn off animation using display:none;? And also looks like Chrome doesn't support such kind of animation with outside css.