# Javascript/JQuery looping the body background color continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having alot of trouble trying to get JQuery and Javascript to loop through an array of colors in a for loop, set the background color of the body to each one, and then restart the process. I don't know if this is the best approach but I want the background color to switch extremely fast. This is what I have so far. Im trying to get it triggered by a JQuery event on a button.

```
$("#button6").click(function() {
    $('#disclaimer').hide();
    $('#button6').hide();
    var colors = Array("red", "green", "blue", "purple" "yellow", "orange);

    var count = 0;
    while ( count < 1000 ) {
    for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        $('body').css("background-color", colors[i]);
        $('body').delay(50);
    }
    count++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.delay()` works with animations, it doesn't delay just anything. I think `setTimeout` would work better for you here:

http://jsfiddle.net/thA9q/

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "orange"];

var currentColor = 0;
function switchColor() {    
    if (currentColor >= colors.length) currentColor = 0;

    $('body').css('background-color', colors[currentColor++]);

    setTimeout(switchColor, 50);
}

switchColor();
```

Answer (score 2):

**look at the bellow snippet.**

```
 var c = ["#81d8d0", "#ffea64", "#89bc84", "#e5cb47", "#9d549c"];
 var i = 0;
 var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 1500);

 function myTimer() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = c[i];
    i = i + 1;
    if (i >= c.length) i = 0;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhaumikmehta/8og7v8ad/6/

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use svg + css?

[Animate svg path fill using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756422/animate-svg-path-fill-using-css)

here is my code:

```
      @keyframes fill {
          0% {
              fill: red;
          }
          20% {
              fill: green;
          }
          40% {
              fill: blue;
          }
          60% {
              fill: purple;
          }
          80% {
              fill: yellow;
          }
          100% {
              fill: orange;
          }
      }

      #fill {
          fill: black;
          animation-name: fill;
          animation-duration: 50ms;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }
    ]]>
</style>
<rect id="fill" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60"/>
```

you can copy it in to a file called something.svg and use it as an image with css.

@edit: somehow the code crashes on stackoverflow, but you can download my sample here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49774783/crazy.svg